# I got a data(token from server) on one controller, and want to use that data(token) in another controller in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

i am getting data from server in form of token in controller named "adminSearchCtrl" and want to use that token  to another controller named "adminViewCtrl"  how to do that??

adminSearchCtrl.js

```
$scope.getUserDetails = function(selectedUser){
        console.log(selectedUser, userToken.token);
        AdminSearchService.getUserDetails(selectedUser, userToken.token)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.switchUserToken = response.switchToken.token;
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            $scope.error = err.message;
        });
    }
```

i want to use this token "$scope.switchUserToken" to another controller named "adminViewCtrl" I have put to $scope also but when i am using "$scope.switchUserToken" to my "adminViewCtrl" it is giving undefined can any body help me out??

Comment: you want to use token in your requests right?

Comment: yes @wickY26 i want to pass token in another controller

Answer (score 1):

Each controller has its own `$scope`, you can't access them from one to another, and **you shouldn't**.

The solution is to create a service to share this data between controllers. Here you have a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xesixo/2/edit?html,js,output) with an example.

Comment: I have used $emit method of angular js but for just one time I am getting the token and the page is refreshed data disappears..?

Comment: It's hard to say without see your code, but I think it's not a good practice to use `$emit` for this purpose. In fact, you should limit the usage of `$broadcast` and `$emit` to only those cases you don't have other choice. Sharing data as I said, is better choice for this.